# Adding python code to firebase side

Tags: python, firebase, ionic-framework

We have an app which is created with Ionic. We used firebase as backend. All authentication and couple of things handled by firebase. We have two major things which are done by python. First we are scraping web for some data and can put it as direct Json file to firebase. Second we have to take some data from firebase, put it on some machine learning library methods and should have new data which again will be stored in firebase.

**Question**

How can I add python code which will be running periodicly in every 24 hours inside firebase for both scraping and machine learning scripts?

**Confusion**

I am not really familiar with server side like I would run python scripts in Apache server or not I have no clue. Since we started with firebase, I have to know how it is done. Python codes are actually ready. I checked python-firebase as well. Evenmore, I have put my machine learning data into firebase. But I do not know where to put this python code. Only thing that I have accomplished is firebase is capable of taking Json files with just one button. I would have not enough knowledge about server-side scripts as well.

**Conclusion**

If someone can enlighten me, I would deeply appreciate that.

Comment: Firebase doesn't offer any backend systems that run Python.  You could use App Engine instead.

Comment: @DougStevenson,I knew it. Even I am not too familiar with firebase, I knew all it can do was saving a Json file nothing more.